# Pandas Dataframe operation to allocate values between two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame df and df1

```
import pandas as pd

# Your original df
data_df = {
    'h': [1, 2, 3],
    'hr': [1235, 1235, 1235],
    'stl': ['stl1', 'stl1', 'stl1'],
    'u': [1, 1, 1],
    'alloc': [156, 156, 156]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_df)

# Your df1
data_df1 = {
    'hr': [1235, 1235, 1235],
    'stl': ['stl1', 'stl1', 'stl1'],
    'u': [1, 1, 1],
    'or': ['order1', 'order2', 'order3'],
    'q': [235, 145, 88]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_df1)
```

Expected output will be

```
    h    hr      stl    u  alloc    or       q
    1   1235    stl1    1   156   order1    156
    2   1235    stl1    1   156   order1    79
    2   1235    stl1    1   156   order2    77
    3   1235    stl1    1   156   order2    68
    3   1235    stl1    1   156   order3    88
```

Assign order numbers to the dataframe df. In each h, I can not exceed the alloc value given that column.

My try:

```
rows_df2 = []

# Iterate through each row in df1
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    hr_filter = df['hr'] == row['hr']
    stl_filter = df['stl'] == row['stl']
    u_filter = df['u'] == row['u']

    # Filter df based on hr, stl, and u
    filtered_rows = df[hr_filter & stl_filter & u_filter]

    # Distribute 'q' from df1 into 'alloc' in df
    allocated_q = min(filtered_rows['alloc'].sum(), row['q'])

    # Append a row to df2
    rows_df2.append({
        'h': row['h'],
        'hr': row['hr'],
        'stl': row['stl'],
        'u': row['u'],
        'alloc': allocated_q,
        'or': row['or'],
        'q': allocated_q
    })

    # Update the 'alloc' value in df
    df.loc[(hr_filter & stl_filter & u_filter), 'alloc'] -= allocated_q

      
# Create df2 from the collected rows
df2 = pd.DataFrame(rows_df2)
```

But my code is not working!! Kindly Help in getting the right code so that I can create the expected output.

Comment: is the count of rows in both dataframes(df, df1) the same?